# Playing large audio files in .net

Tags: .net

We are having our own application that has to be deployed with our big audio wav files (up to 700 MB). Audio files have to be hidden so we are thinking about putting it into resource file.

The problem is that resource file is too big to build, and we are not sure if resource files are loaded into memory along with application or on demand?

What would be alternative? How to store and load big wav files so they can be fetched from application directly and still not visible from oustide?

---

*Further information copied from "answer":*

Just to make clear. I dont want bullet proof system or something like that. Simple idea is that file cant be just c/p and used.

I am thinking if it could be possible to encrypt it, than read with FileStream, put FileStream into CryptoStream and CryptoStream to DirectSound?

When reading it like that, is whole file decrypted in front or it is being encrypted as it is being read on the go?

Comment: Why do you want to hide the audio file? If you're doing that because you think this way you'll prevent the user from "grabbing" it, won't work.

Comment: This kind of obfuscation never works.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename them to `.dat` and perform some simple pseudo-encryption like rot13, an experienced user would find the way to extract them anyway.
It's a useless idea to make a 700mb exe file.

Comment: It won't work even using AES or any other strong encryption algorithm. To have the file played back on my computer, you must first decrypt it. Eventually the file must return to its original form to be played, and I can grab it then.

Comment: I mean the developer can write a StreamReader that would "decrypt" it on the fly and play.

Comment: It won't work. I can still hijack the audio stream before it gets to the sound card and record it. E.g. on a Mac you can so it through SoundFlower.

Comment: I am aware of the analog hole and that is ok. I just dont want to make files directly visible to the users and that is it. I am thinking if it could be possible to encrypt it, than read with FileStream, put FileStream into CryptoStream and CryptoStream to DirectAudio?

Comment: I don't know how .NET handles encryption, make sure you don't need to load the whole file in memory to decrypt it or you're screwed. If you can decrypt it on the fly you could use this method.

Comment: I will try if it is possible to do it on the fly. If .NET encryption doesnt work Iwill make inherited FileStream with simple byte-wise encryption/decryption.

Answer (score 0):

"still not visible from outside"? don't know about you, but I guess it's in the 700+ MB file! You can't hide the filesize, and if the user knows where the file is he can find a way to extract it (including resource files). Maybe you can split it in a number of small files without a logical naming order and recreate it in a stream to play it. Some pseudo-encryption also might help a little...

This all only makes it harder to crack, but if the user really wants to get the file (and has some time to spend) he can.

Comment: We dont want to make it impossible to crack, we just dont want to have clearly visible files that you can just c/p.